# MSBuild & Nuget without Visual Studio installed does not execute build extension targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

We want to build dotnet projects on a system without VS installed. We installed latest 4.6.2 dotnet dev tools and sdk and msbuild-tools 12.0.

No Visual Studio installed.

We have a nuget package, that implements an additional build step. It works in VS Express, and on the msbuild commandline, when VS Express is installed, but not without any VS installed.

The package is downloaded from the server and placed into the packages folder of the solution.

Yet, the custom build step in the package is not executed on build - Why? 
What are we missing?

This is the nuget package:

```
\Package.nuspec
\build\nugetPostbuild.targets
\script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd
```

The targets file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="postbuildPackNuGetTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Message from MyNuGetCustomTarget. Configuration: $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\nuget_postbuild_script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectFileName) $(ConfigurationName) $(TargetDir)" />
        <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\nuget_postbuild_script\createPackageAndUpload.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectFileName) $(ConfigurationName) $(TargetDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The spec is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>nugetPostbuild</id>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <authors>thewindowsuser</authors>
    <owners>thewindowsuser</owners>
    <projectUrl>http://...</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>bla ...</description>
    <releaseNotes>http://...</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright ...</copyright>
    <tags>some tags here</tags>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="script\**" target="nuget_postbuild_script" />
        <file src="build\**" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

UPDATE:

In a .csproj file where the package works, I found the following import:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\nugetPostbuild.1.0.3\build\nugetPostbuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\nugetPostbuild.1.0.3\build\nugetPostbuild.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup> ... error text removed ...</PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\nugetPostbuild.1.0.3\build\nugetPostbuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\nugetPostbuild.1.0.3\build\nugetPostbuild.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Have these been added by nuget or by Visual Studio? I expect them to be added from nuget, but this seems not to happen.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It does not execute the build step.

Comment: it does not execute "postbuildPackNuGetTarget", does it?

Comment: Yes, it does not execute the postbuildPackNuGetTarget. It should at least post the message, even if the script fails.